# Timeline view inside AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to create a TimeLine UI in an AlertDialog in Flutter? And if so, how is it possible?

Comment: define "TimeLine UI"

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903601/custom-timeline-view-in-flutter

Comment: `AlertDialog` has `Widget content` property - it can be any `Widget` - so you can use `ListView` or `CustomScrollView` or `SingleChildScrollView` to show such a list

Comment: good! besides it's necessary use a `Container` with specified dimensions that contains `TimeLine`

Comment: yes, i found it too ;-)